# How can I Make navbar menu stay on one line only?

Tags: css, flexbox, menu, navbar

I'm trying to create a simple sticky navbar with 3 divs:
-one on the most left part (that contains image logo + text logo)
-one of the center (that contains the actual menu)
-one on the most right part (that contains social icons)

So far so good managed to work around with flex and stuff but on one of the menu's items I have a section "why us", and it's on two lines instead of one. How can I fix this? Here's how it looks now:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6F2U.png)

here's the code I have so far:

```css
body {
  background-color: #A8DADC;
}

#navbar {
  background-color: #457B9D;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: row;
  gap: 10px;
}

#logo-stuff {
  display: inline-flex;
  order: 1;
  align-self: center;
  background-color: green;
}

#logo-text {
  display: flex;
  align-self: center;
}

#logo-img {
  width: 30%;
}

#links {
  order: 2;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-self: center;
  padding: 0px 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

#socials {
  order: 3;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0px 70px;
  align-self: center;
}

.nav-link {
  color: white;
  font-size: large;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<header id="header">
  <nav id="navbar">
    <div id="logo-stuff">
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/GMSp6tR/Pngtree-blue-assassin-esports-logo-for-4295380.png" alt="" id="logo-img">
      <h1 id="logo-text">Gaming Den</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="links">
      <a href="#home" class="nav-link">Home</a>
      <a href="#whyus" class="nav-link" id="whyus">Why us</a>
      <a href="#pricing" class="nav-link">Pricing</a>
      <a href="#contact" class="nav-link">Contact</a>
    </div>
    <div id="socials">Socials</div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: try `whitespace:no-wrap`.

Answer (score 0):

[`white-space: nowrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) is a very common fix for this, but it could be problematic if not used correctly, or if it's not needed. In your case with `nav-links` wrapping is just because there is no width defined so the browser doesn't know when to stop shrinking it when resizing. I added `width: 100%;` to your `#links` as well as `min-width: fit-content;` which allows your text not to wrap when resizing.

Now, that fixes your issue of the navbar not being all in one line... what else could you do?

Now that you know how `min-width` works, we can set it in a few other places. If you're going to use `%` to define the width of your image, I would specify a min-width so that it doesn't get "too cropped" when on a media device. I specified one.

Now a perfect example for `white-space: nowrap;` - if you set `min-width` on #logo-text the text won't wrap which is good, but you will notice the green container doesn't always fit the text when resizing. Easy fix, this is where `white-space: nowrap;` comes in.

```css
body {
  background-color: #A8DADC;
}

#navbar {
  background-color: #457B9D;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: row;
  gap: 10px;
}

#logo-stuff {
  display: inline-flex;
  order: 1;
  align-self: center;
  background-color: green;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#logo-text {
  display: flex;
  align-self: center;
  min-width: fit-content;
}

#logo-img {
  width: 30%;
  min-width: 60px;
}

#links {
  order: 2;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-self: center;
  padding: 0px 20px;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: fit-content;

}

#socials {
  order: 3;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0px 70px;
  align-self: center;
}

.nav-link {
  color: white;
  font-size: large;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<header id="header">
  <nav id="navbar">
    <div id="logo-stuff">
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/GMSp6tR/Pngtree-blue-assassin-esports-logo-for-4295380.png" alt="" id="logo-img">
      <h1 id="logo-text">Gaming Den</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="links">
      <a href="#home" class="nav-link">Home</a>
      <a href="#whyus" class="nav-link" id="whyus">Why us</a>
      <a href="#pricing" class="nav-link">Pricing</a>
      <a href="#contact" class="nav-link">Contact</a>
    </div>
    <div id="socials">Socials</div>
  </nav>
</header>
```